# Setting maven repository

Tags: java, maven

I was needed for javax.xml package for my new project. I did search in mvnrepository.com and found [one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1) :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0_EA1</version>
</dependency>
```

I suppose, first comment line is package repository. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. I added following sections in my `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repo1</id>
    <name>Repo 1</name>
    <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0_EA1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But looks I got wrong maven address.

`mvn compile` brought error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-xpath: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.kkk:test-xpath:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:2.0_EA1 in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo1 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

What I did wrong and how to fix that?

UPD

After removing repository I got error:

```
 Failed to execute goal on project test-xpath: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.kkk:test-xpath:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:2.0_EA1 in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo1 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

UPD2

I have learned that I should add spring repository to my dependencies:

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repo1</id>
      <name>Repo 1</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

I have deleted `.m2\repository\javax` and did `maven clean`

`maven compile` produced error:

```
Downloading from repo1: http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/jaxrpc-api-2.0_EA1.pom
Downloaded from repo1: http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/jaxrpc-api-2.0_EA1.pom (395 B at 736 B/s)
Downloading from repo1: http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/jaxrpc-api-2.0_EA1.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/jaxrpc-api-2.0_EA1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.767 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-07T14:17:38+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-xpath: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.kkk:test-xpath:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:2.0_EA1 in repo1 (http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/), try downloading from https://jax-rpc.dev.java.net/jaxrpc20-ea/ -> [Help 1]
```

In case I do the same action without `<repository>` in my pom.xml  and do `maven compile` I have the same error, but it tries to download pom from `maven.repo`.

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/jaxrpc-api-2.0_EA1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/jaxrpc-api-2.0_EA1.pom (395 B at 987 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/jaxrpc-api-2.0_EA1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.180 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-07T14:31:44+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-xpath: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.kpv:test-xpath:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:2.0_EA1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2), try downloading from https://jax-rpc.dev.java.net/jaxrpc20-ea/ -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I think maybe you have a provlem with this there is no version 5.2.0.Final according to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager

Try 5.2.2.Final

Comment: `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api` is **not** a repository URL. And the official Maven repo is already among the default repositories, no need to add it. Just remove it and everything will work as expected

Comment: Remove repositories tag entirely, doesn't make any sense at all since that url is not a Maven repository.

Comment: @AKSW After removing repository I got error `Failed to execute goal on project test-xpath: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.kkk:test-xpath:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:2.0_EA1 in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo1 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

That is not the proper use of repository tag. If you go to https://mvnrepository.com main page you'll see that it makes indices from multiple repositories, such as central, jcenter, etc. So you have to use standard repositories.

Comment: Where I can find list of standard repositories? Does my maven2 eclipse plugin knows about them? Removing `repositories` not helped. More details in question body UPD

Answer (score 0):

if we open [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api) page, we can see two tabs: Central and Spring Plugins. Open Spring plugins tab, and try to use it, because that version is fresh, and dated April of 2018.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0_ea1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, run `mvn clean` command, and to be sure, delete `javax` folder in `.m2` location.

Comment: `mvn clean` reports `BUILD SUCCES`, but not deletes `.m2\repository\javax`. Why?

Comment: Yes, version in Spring repo is fresh, but how to ask maven to download from it? Should I add `http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release` to `pom.xml`  `repositories` ?

Comment: @vico, delete folder manually from `.m2` folder. just add dependency, no additional repo required.

Comment: Did as recommended. More details in UPD2, in question body. Maven finds pom, but fails to find jar.

Answer (score 0):

2.0_EA1 doesn't exists on Maven central. if you use 1.1 you will see that it works. The non normalized semver version seem to relate to a non official version, maybe  an alpha version.
The search on search.maven.org claims it exists, but the jar itself doesn't exists

To check with a working version:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also note: The error maven displays tell you that you can download the jar manually from an url, it's not a repository.

To answer only the title of the question you can add a repository to your pom.xml, but the central maven repository dosen't need to be added, so I give you an example for another repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack</id>
        <name>jitpack</name>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: `<version>1.1</version>` solves the problem. But how to work with maven in normal way. Is there any official release of popular packages?

Comment: @vico You did search well and just fall in the rare case of mispackaged project: its pom description exist but not the jar, the distributor is to blame. Scan the maven url and you will find the pom : bad packaging: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/2.0_EA1/ good packaging : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/jaxrpc-api/1.1/