# Official javax maven repository

Tags: java, maven

I need `javax.xm`l package. For this reason I go to `mvnrepository.com` and do search. As result I have big list of [repositories](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=javax.xml) . How to know which one is right?

Comment: what class do you need exactly from the package or what are you trying to implement ? javax.xml is a groupid and there may be n number of artifacts under the group id. so be more specific on what you need

Comment: Those are not repositories in maven way, just a browsable list of artefacts.

Comment: I need `javax.xml.xpath `

Comment: That's not helpful...and it's a bit unfortunate that you "forgot" to mention what you really want, namely `jaxrpc-api` artifact, according to his [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187425/setting-maven-repository)  - I don't think that this in in Java SE. The package can be contained in multiple artifacts, more important are the classes. And in the end, it doesn't matter which repo you use as long as it works. you should do the comparison and decide on the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.xml.xpath` package is part of Java SE.  You should not need a Maven dependency for it.

But if you do, you have a problem because (AFAIK) Oracle doesn't have an official public maven repository, and (AFAIK) they don't officially condone the uploading of their APIs to Maven Central.

---

If you are actually looking for a `jaxrpc-api` maven artifact:

- It is deprecated.  You should be migrating to JAX-WS 2.0; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML-based_RPC).
- The (legacy) JAXRPC 1.1 API source code can be found [here](https://github.com/javaee/jax-rpc-ri).  You should be able to build your own JAR from it, then add it to your local repo.
- It looks like Apache Axis has solved the problem that jaxrpc-api 1.1 has been "disappeared" by taking their own copy; see [JAXRPC API](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/jaxrpc/project-summary.html)  project page.

Comment: a bit unfortunate that he "forgot" to mention what he wants, namely `jaxrpc-api` artifact, according to his [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187425/setting-maven-repository)  - I don't think that this in in Java SE

Comment: Actually, he said (here) that he is looking for `javax.xml.xpath`; see above.

Comment: yeah, I know - I just wanted to say that he might forgot to say what he really wants which I know from his previous thread. anyways, you gave the correct answer